# Onclick open new window and reload previous page

Tags: facebook, popup, refresh, reload

I trying to have a new window pop up to checkout at Paypal, OK. Problem is that if user goes back to add or take away items and click "checkout" again, the pop up does not work. The only solution I can think of is when customer submits form to check out, the action opens up a new window and reloads the page they were just on. Can this be done or is there another way?

checkoutPayment: ' {payment}',

```
paypal: '<form target="_blank" id="rcCartForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr;" method="post">' +
```